# Generating a character-type pattern of a field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to look at the character content of a field, then produce a count of character-type patterns in that field. So a value of 'SomeStuff 123' would have a pattern of 'XXXXXXXXX 999'.

I have a couple of ways of doing this already but they seem long and clumsy. I'd like to find the shortest/most elegant way of doing this.

I'm thinking PATINDEX might be the way to go:

```
Select 
    Pattern = 
    Case 
        When PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Left([MyField], 1)) = 1 Then '9' 
        When PatIndex('%[a-Z]%', Left([MyField], 1)) = 1 Then 'X' 
        When PatIndex('% %', Left([MyField], 1)) = 1 Then ' '
        Else '?'
    End 
+ 
    Case
        When PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 1 Then '9' 
        When PatIndex('%[a-Z]%', Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 1 Then 'X' 
        When PatIndex('% %', Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 1 Then ' ' 
        Else '?'
    End 
--...
```

Here are a couple of ways I have tested which work:

Literal REPLACE method:

```
Select [MyFieldPattern] = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([MyField], 'A','X') ,'B','X') ,'C','X') ,'D','X') ,'E','X') ,'F','X') ,'G','X') ,'H','X') ,'I','X') ,'J','X') ,'K','X') ,'L','X') ,'M','X') ,'N','X') ,'O','X') ,'P','X') ,'Q','X') ,'R','X') ,'S','X') ,'T','X') ,'U','X') ,'V','X') ,'W','X') ,'Y','X') ,'Z','X') ,'0','1') ,'2','1') ,'3','1') ,'4','1') ,'5','1') ,'6','1') ,'7','1') ,'8','1') ,'9','1') 
, Count(*) As Counts
 From [MyDatabase]
Group By 
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([MyField], 'A','X') ,'B','X') ,'C','X') ,'D','X') ,'E','X') ,'F','X') ,'G','X') ,'H','X') ,'I','X') ,'J','X') ,'K','X') ,'L','X') ,'M','X') ,'N','X') ,'O','X') ,'P','X') ,'Q','X') ,'R','X') ,'S','X') ,'T','X') ,'U','X') ,'V','X') ,'W','X') ,'Y','X') ,'Z','X') ,'0','1') ,'2','1') ,'3','1') ,'4','1') ,'5','1') ,'6','1') ,'7','1') ,'8','1') ,'9','1') 
Order By Count(*) Desc
```

Brute force CASE method:

```
Select
    FieldName_Analyzed =        Convert(VarChar(15), 'MyField'),
    Literal_Value_Aggregated =  Convert(VarChar(30), 
          Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) = 72 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) = 82 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) = 92 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) = 102 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) = 112 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) = 122 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) = 132 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) = 142 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) = 152 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        ),
    Percent_Populated =         Convert(Decimal(5,2), Convert(Decimal(5,4), Convert(Float, Count(
          Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) = 72 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) = 82 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) = 92 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) = 102 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) = 112 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) = 122 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) = 132 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) = 142 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) = 152 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        ))/(Select Count(*) From [MyDatabase]))*100),
    Total_Count =               Convert(Int, Count(
          Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) = 72 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) = 82 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) = 92 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) = 102 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) = 112 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) = 122 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) = 132 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) = 142 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) = 152 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        ))
    From [MyDatabase]
    Group By 
          Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) = 72 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) = 82 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) = 92 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) = 102 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) = 112 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) = 122 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) = 132 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) = 142 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) = 152 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
    Order By
          Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 1, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 2, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 3, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 4, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 5, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) = 32 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 6, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) = 72 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 7, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) = 82 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 8, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) = 92 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 9, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) = 102 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 10, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) = 112 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 11, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) = 122 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 12, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) = 132 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 13, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) = 142 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 14, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
        + Convert(VarChar(1), Case When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 48 And 57 Then '9' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Between 65 And 122 Then 'X' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) = 152 Then '_' When ASCII(Substring([MyField], 15, 1)) Is Null Then Char(216) Else '?' End)
    Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another way

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,MyField varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'SomeStuff 123')

Select A.ID
      ,A.MyField
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewString=replace(Stuff((Select ''+C From (
                                    Select C=case when C Like '[0-9]' then '9' else
                                             case when C = ' ' then '§§Space§§' else 'X' end end
                                     From (Select Top (len(A.MyField)) C=substring(A.MyField,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),1) From master..spt_values ) B1
                                   ) C1 For XML Path ('')),1,0,''),'§§Space§§',' ')
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  MyField         NewString
1   SomeStuff 123   XXXXXXXXX 999
```